# attaching usb device to android gphone host

Tags: android

is it possible to mount another usb device x to gphone and then create a program that communites to x on the usb port?  X is used for capturing data and gphone will be used for analysis/display.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand a bit more about USB.  There are (neglecting OTG) two sides to USB: a Host (typically your PC) and a Client (your G1).  The physical hardware requirements for the two are different.  Your G1 has the client hardware and drivers, so you can't plug another client (like a keyboard) into it.  Even if you had the cable adapter you don't have the physical interface or driver to run it.